# Using CSS3 for conditional styling?

Tags: javascript, css, html

Ok, so here's the scenario:

Say I have a setup like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <span></span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And I'm using CSS to set styles for the li's to be large floating boxes...
Using css's :hover and :active (conditions?) to change the style, such as the background color and height and so on...

Now, question - Using JUST css, can I define it so that:

- Natively, Li's have 100px height, and the span has 0px height
- on Hover, the li's height increases to 150px, and the span's height increases to 50px?

This will result in an animation that looks like a box with plain text, when hovered upon will reveal an image to supplement the text.

EDIT - Here's a link to a fiddle demonstrating what I was aiming for. The yellow portion is supposed to be an external image. This was achieved by implementing the solution provided within this question.

http://jsfiddle.net/abhi/JMz8F/2/embedded/result/

Comment: hover and active are pseudo classes in CSS  -> http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#pseudo-elements

Comment: Ah, that's what they're called... Thanks for the heads up mate...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're talking specifically about css3 animation, I assume you don't care about internet explorer, nor older versions of browsers.

With that out of the way, see this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/ZYaKh/3/

Comment: Lol, yeah... I'm doing this more for the sake of learning and doing cool things on browsers, so yeah, I am not commercializing anything that might require conformance to IE or older browsers...

Comment: !!! Wow, I did NOT think of using the CSS3 selectors like that... When the element li is hovered upon, change CSS properties for one of its child elements... Interesting... I think you've effectively solved my problem... Lemme just test this in my implementation...

Comment: Ok, this did the trick... Thank you so much... Adding a link to what I was trying to achieve anyways...

Answer (score 4):

```
li { height: 100px }
li > span { display: none; height: 50px }
li:hover { height: 150px }
li:hover > span { display: block }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
li { height: 100px; }
li span { height: 0; }

li:hover { height: 150px; }
li:hover span { height: 50px; }
```

BTW, `:hover` is simply called a *pseudo-class*. Also, `:hover` support on non-link elements is sketchy in IE7 and below.

Comment: By default `span` has `display: inline` which means `height` has no effect.

Comment: @Mike I read that the OP has already "set them up as large floating boxes", but maybe he's just talking about the `li`s.

Comment: Lol, I realize that its easiest to give everyone a fiddle to know what I'm talking about... Will update the OP to add a link to the same...

Answer (score 2):

Animations can be done with the `transition` property and its sub-properties, plus browser specific prefixes (currently `-webkit-`, `-moz-`, `-o-`, and `-khtml-`):

```
transition: height 0.5s ease-in-out; /* transition the height for half a second using 2-way easing */
```

You can add multiple properties and use a cubic Bézier curve for the easing function, too. Lots of great resources can be found by Googling around.